# Mapping text field to enum in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, enums

I want to map my input text field to java enum type. Is it possible for me to map input text field to java enum in JSF. I dont want to use drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just bind it to the enum property directly the usual way. JSF/EL has builtin converters for enums.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.someEnum}" />
```

with

```
private SomeEnum someEnum;
```

You only need to deal with the fact that the entered value has to **exactly** match the enum name, otherwise a conversion error will show up.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, in UX perspective a dropdown list is *so much* more userfriendly for specifying one of a set of constants than an input text field where the enduser can easily make typos or have a hard time in memorizing the allowed values. That's exactly the reason why an enum property is often used in combination with a dropdown list or radio buttons, it's not a technical limitation of enum properties.